# Return InstanceType<T> OR undefined

Tags: typescript

I'm creating a registry where if I pass in a class to a `Map` as a key, it will return an instance of that class as a value.

```
class Car {}
class HondaCar extends Car{}

type Newable = { new (...args: unknown[]): unknown };

export default class CarRegistry {
  private cars = new Map<NewableFunction, Car>();

  register(instance: Car) {
    this.cars.set(instance.constructor, instance);
  }

  get<T extends Newable>(type: T) {
    if (!this.cars.has(type)) return undefined;
    return this.cars.get(type) as InstanceType<T>;
  }
}
```

The expected functionality is something like:

```
const registry = new CarRegistry()
registry.register(new HondaCar())
car = registry.cars.get(HondaCar)
```

The issue, however, is that I want `register.cars.get` to be able to return `undefined`. For some reason, no matter what combination of types I try for `get`, it's not possible in this context to return `undefined`. Here's the signature TypeScript generates for me:

```
(method) CarRegistry.get<typeof HondaCar>(type: typeof HondaCar): HondaCar
```

The types are completely correct, which is great, but I want this function to return `HondaCar | undefined`. This is necessary because there is a large chance that the car has not yet been registered, and I want the caller to account for that.

Is there any way I can return `InstanceType<T>` OR `undefined`?

Comment: When you're done editing this I hope it will be a [mre] that demonstrates your issue when pasted into a standalone IDE. Right now [I see errors unrelated to your question](https://tsplay.dev/m362EN) and it's not clear to me what problem you have (you describe it in English but are not showing with code, or at least not pointing out exactly where in the code the problem is and how it manifests).

Comment: @jcalz yeah that's my bad. It's taken from a real codebase so I'm having to adjust the naming. Sorry about that.

Comment: @jcalz this is so strange. For some reason, the error is correctly appearing on the playground. But it's not appearing for me in the IDE. I copy pasted this exact solution in both the IDE and the playground and I'm getting the error I expect in the playground.

Comment: Oh my goodness `strictNullChecks` were disabled :facepalm:

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if `strictNullChecks` are disabled. Enabling `"strict": true` in my TSConfig resolved my issue.